# How to read .zip files in Synapse spark notebooks

Tags: azure-synapse

I'm new to the synapse. I am stuck in a problem. I want to read the '.zip' file from an ADLS gen2 via spark notebooks. I Hope spark.read.csv doesn't support '.zip' compression. And I also tried to read using python zipFile libraries but it does not accept the ABFSS path. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like pandas.read_csv supports on the fly unzip, if you can get it to read ADLS https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly new to Synapse so this may not be a definitive answer, but I dont think it is possible.

I have tried the following approaches:

1. zipfile with abfss:// path (as you have)
2. zipfile with synfs:// path
3. shutil with synfs:// path
4. copy file to tempdir and use shutil (could not get this to work)